# Nautilus icon missing (after uninstalling Macbuntu 10.10 customization pack)

Tags: nautilus, themes, icons

After using Macbuntu 10.10 theme for a while, I uninstalled it using supplied `uninstall.sh` file, and now Nautilus icon is missing, and none of the icon theme is showing it. I also found that the launcher of Nautilus i.e. `nautilus-browser.desktop` is missing in `/usr/share/applications/` folder. Now icon looks like that of binary file's icon instead of Nautilus'.

How can I revert this icon back to normal...

Answer (score 3):

Try reinstalling Nautilus and the theme containing the icon:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus gnome-icon-theme
```

Comment: An Update to Nautilus elementary resolved the issue on that very day, though I'm still looking for a fix to such issue without having to re-install Nautilus, like in Windows, we can re-build icon cache to fix any icon annoyances, why can't we do the same with Linux? which is actually more flexible.

Comment: If an icon is missing, you have to restore it. If a .desktop file is missing, you have to restore. You should be more worried about why those files went missing in the first place. If you don't want to face such problems I suggest staying away from unsupported third-party software.

Comment: Exactly, I care for missing system files rather than just an icon, so I was looking for way to restore those files (either creating them manually), without having to re-install entire package.